# (springboot + hibernate + jparepository) Error - no session, whe tying to GET

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this SpringBoot project, where one property of my entity is LAZY, but when i try to GET the table that depends on this entity (I'm just rtying to use Postman), i keep getting this error-

```
{
    "timestamp": 1545232817105,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: br.com.quantus.fonumS3_api.model.GesUsuarios.fnmCampanhaOpesForFnmCampanhaOpeOperador, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: br.com.quantus.fonumS3_api.model.GesUsuarios.fnmCampanhaOpesForFnmCampanhaOpeOperador, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->br.com.quantus.fonumS3_api.model.GesUsuarios[\"fnmCampanhaOpesForFnmCampanhaOpeOperador\"])",
    "path": "/FonumAPI/GesUsuarios"
}
```

This is how i'm setting up my models, repos and resources:

```
//MODEL
@Entity
@Table(name = "ges_usuarios_015", schema = "public", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "login_015"))
public class GesUsuarios implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6598890791981509364L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "codigo_015", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer codigo015;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "turno_015")
    private GerTurno gerTurno;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_015")
    private GerTipoUsuario gerTipoUsuario;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "status_015")
    private GerStatusUsuario gerStatusUsuario;
    ....


//REPOSITORY
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import model.GesUsuarios;

public interface GesUsuariosRepository extends JpaRepository<GesUsuarios, Integer> {

}

//RESOURCE
@CrossOrigin("${origem-permitida}")
@RestController
public class GesUsuariosResource {

    @Autowired
    private GesUsuariosRepository gesUsuariosRepository;    

    @GetMapping("/GesUsuarios")
    public List<GesUsuarios> ListarGesUsuarios(){   
    return gesUsuariosRepository.findAll();
    }
    ....
```

I can't use EAGER, because I have tons of data in my db, so it gets quite slow. When using LAZY, on the other hand, I keep getting this problem. 
I believe it's because jpa is closing its session before consulting the foreign key's model.

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: I recommend reading the following article to solve your [problem](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/)

Answer (score 0):

In the solution above you are retrieving a model and sending it directly out as part of a response. During this process your response attempts to access those fields to convert it to a send-able format (xml/json/text).

What should be done here if you want those fields to simply be null, is create a representational model where you map the entity fields to a representation and simply skip the lazily loaded fields (a new query will be created if/when you attempt to access these fields when mapping to a representation).

A spring boot representation is simply a POJO with no additional JPA annotations (like your entity has) this will automatically be converted to the type your end-point produces.

In your code specifically after this is created it will look something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/GesUsuarios")
    public List<GesUsuarios> ListarGesUsuarios(){
    List<GesUsuarios> usuariosModels = gesUsuariosRepository.findAll();
    List<UsuariosRepresentation> usuarios;

    for(GesUsuarios usuariosModel : usuarios) {
      UsuariosRepresentation usuario = new UsuariosRepresentation();

      usuario.setField1(usuariosModel.getField1());
      ... //Do not include the lazily loaded pieces here, unless  you specifically want them.

      usuarios.add(usuario);
    }

    return usuarios;
}
```

Lastly, I would take a look at returning Optionals from your repositories as well, they are quite useful here.

Optional Reading:
[Baeldung - Optionals](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional)

Comment: The thing is, i cannot ignore it, i need to the the foreign key's value on my get

Comment: So if you need the foreign key, you will need to create a query that joins those fields in, but only retrieves the key of the additional tables

@Query("select u from GesUsuarios u join fetch u.gerTurno join fetch u.gerTipoUsuario join fetch u.gerStatusUsuario")

Then once you call this, and you are filling your representations in, you can grab only the foreign keys from those joined tables. In your example above this will be in your repository as:

@Query("..") and have findAll(); directly underneath

Comment: Adding a second comment for this, i didn't discuss it at all here, but you might prefer a native query for this. @Query(value="query..." nativeQuery=true) List<Object[]>> findAll where the list will be rows and the object array will be columns. Then you can map to a representation without worrying about jql/hql